# Extraction of the perimeter of points clouds from triangle.plot

Tags: r, plot, colors, rgb

I have 3 points clouds into a `triangle.plot` from `ade4` package:

[image: triangle.plot result]

These points are come from RGB data which are in an object (RGB0) like this:

```
head(RGB0)
      R  G  B
[1,] 87 92 69
[2,] 87 92 69
[3,] 88 93 70
[4,] 88 93 70
[5,] 89 94 71
[6,] 89 94 71
...
```

Each points clouds come from its own dataset file:

- file for green points: filehosting.org/file/details/655417/green.txt
- file for yellow points: filehosting.org/file/details/655383/yellow.txt
- file for red points: filehosting.org/file/details/655420/yellow.txt

And there is the code for the triangle.plot with data:

```
library(ade4)

data2= as.data.frame(RGB0) 
head(RGB0)  

data2$R <- RGB0[,1]/255     
data2$G <- RGB0[,2]/255
data2$B <- RGB0[,3]/255
head(data2)


triangle.plot <- triangle.plot(data2, clab = 0, cpoi = 2, addmean = F, show = FALSE, addaxes = F, scale = F)
points(triangle.plot, pch = 19, cex = 1, col = nacreHEX)
```

My question is how can I get the perimeter of these 3 clouds, and how can I draw it into the `triangle.plot` ?

Comment: @42 thanks for yours advices, I cut the data into three files (see edit). But I haven't find a way how to draw a convex hull around data into triangle.plot. It's easy with "2 columns datas" but I didn't find a way yet with "3 columns datas".

Comment: Yes indeed, this was the point I had missed to understand this problem. Thanks !

Comment: I'm posting this exchange as an answer (and deleting the comments)  but it would be of more benefit to future viewers if you would post the code and then give yourself the checkmark. (I'm not in need of rep at this point, but I do support giving credit for code.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to design a dataframe that identifies the group membership first and if you don't have group membership, then that's the hard part), and then draw a convex hull around each group separately (easy part). So if the "3 point clouds" are separate files, then why not edit your question to include some data for illustration purposes? – 42- Apr 6 '17 at 20:32

@42 thanks for yours advice, I cut the data into three files (see edit). But I haven't find a way how to draw a convex hull around data into triangle.plot. It's easy with "2 columns datas" but I didn't find a way yet with "3 columns datas". – Pierre-louis Stenger Apr 7 '17 at 1:26

Ternary plots are really only 2-dimensional. You can draw a convex hull around any two sets of coordinates and infer the third (non-dimension). – 42- Apr 7 '17 at 4:13

Yes indeed, this was the point I had missed to understand this problem.

Further note: ternary plots provide a display mechanism for 3-attribute data that is restricted to 100% summation, i.e compositional. As such it is properly modeled wtih Dirichlet distributions.